# Android shell sed trouble

Tags: android, shell, sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove all instances of text enclosed by square brackets from a document, so my code is:

```
sed -r 's|\[[^\]]*\]||g' file
```

However, this does not seem to pick up all instances of text enclosed by square brackets. In particular, it seems to fail with:

```
[/a]
[/b]
[span style "blah" blah]
```

and so forth, but it works with square brackets enclosing plaintext. As far as I can tell, the regex should be looking for square brackets enclosing any character that is not a ], so what exactly is wrong?

Comment: How is this related to Android?

Comment: Missed this. It's because I'm writing the script specifically for the Android Shell, which uses Busybox. The utilities aren't _quite_ the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this regex and it didn't remove *any* text in brackets.

When I removed that second '\', so the regex was

```
 sed -r 's|\[[^]]*\]||g'
```

it worked perfectly in all cases.

I tried it on both Mac and Linux. Android runs Linux, so it will probably work there too.

---

A word of explanation: Scansets are special where escapes are concerned. If the ']' character is the very first one in the scanset, you don't need to escape it. If it's not the very first one in the scanset, you *can't* escape it.

Comment: That works, thank you. But I just tested the sed again with the escaped ], and it _does_ work as I said: it removed _some_ text in square brackets but not all. Any idea why?